# PHP filter JSON array with $_POST array

Tags: php, json, search, filter

I currently have a json file that contains vehicle information:

```
{
    "Inventory": [{
            "id": "1",
            "StockNumber": "1000",
            "Make": "Ford",
            "Model": "Mustang",
            "Trim": "GT",
            "Year": "2011",
            "Color": "Red",
            "Cylinders": "8",
            "Transmission": "Manual"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "StockNumber": "1001",
            "Make": "Ford",
            "Model": "Mustang",
            "Trim": "GT",
            "Year": "2012",
            "Color": "Yellow",
            "Cylinders": "8",
            "Transmission": "Automatic"
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "StockNumber": "1002",
            "Make": "Chevy",
            "Model": "Camaro",
            "Trim": "ZL1",
            "Year": "2020",
            "Color": "Red",
            "Cylinders": "8",
            "Transmission": "Manual"
        }]
}
```

I am trying to have checkboxes filter the results by Make, Model, Year, Color, etc....  From the selection page, I get the value of the checkboxes, and pass it to the search php page.  This is the array that is passed to the search page.

['Model' => ['Mustang', 'Camaro'],'Color' => ['Red']];

This should return 2 results, a red Mustang, and a red Camaro.

If I use `array_filter`, after selecting Ford, the Chevy vehicles are now filtered out.  So I can select Ford, and Red, I would get the one result as expected.  However, now I cannot select Chevy as it has been filtered out. So I cannot see the Ford and Chevy vehicles that are red.  I get one result, a red Mustang.

If I try to add vehicles to a results array using array_push, I can add Ford, and Chevy, but selecting red does not filter out the yellow Mustang because the yellow Mustang is a Ford, and it matches that criteria.  I get 3 results, 1 red Mustang, 1 yellow Mustang, and 1 red Camaro.

I am struggling with the logic to filter the json results using the array that is passed in.  It seems I need to `"or"` multiple makes that are passed in, and `"and"` each category.  Ford OR Chevy AND Red.  Another example may be: Ford OR Chevy AND Red OR Yellow AND Manual.

I have updated the code based on the reply below:

```
$make = ['Mustang', 'Camaro'];
$color = ['Red'];

$result = [];

   foreach ($dataSource as $k => $data) {
   
      foreach ($posts as $postKey => $postValue) {
    
     
     // This does not.  Only filters on last array in loop
     if (array_key_exists($postKey, $data) && in_array($data[$postKey], 
     $postValue)) {
    
      $result[$k] = $data;
        } else {
      unset($result[$k]);
            }
         }
       }
     }
```

How do I filter this array based on the array criteria dynamically in a way that the static example works?

Comment: why would a database not an option? they are clearly made for this purpose.

Comment: Because sometimes you have to work with what you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the post array into this structure for easier handling

```
 $posts = [
        'Model' => ['Mustang', 'Camero'],
        'Color' => ['Red']
    ];
```

Then use foreach filter:

```
        $carJson = '{
    "Inventory": [{
            "id": "1",
            "StockNumber": "1000",
            "Make": "Ford",
            "Model": "Mustang",
            "Trim": "GT",
            "Year": "2011",
            "Color": "Red",
            "Cylinders": "8",
            "Transmission": "Manual"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "StockNumber": "1001",
            "Make": "Ford",
            "Model": "Mustang",
            "Trim": "GT",
            "Year": "2012",
            "Color": "Yellow",
            "Cylinders": "8",
            "Transmission": "Automatic"
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "StockNumber": "1002",
            "Make": "Chevy",
            "Model": "Camaro",
            "Trim": "ZL1",
            "Year": "2020",
            "Color": "Red",
            "Cylinders": "8",
            "Transmission": "Manual"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "StockNumber": "1005",
            "Make": "Chevy",
            "Model": "VW",
            "Trim": "ZL1",
            "Year": "2020",
            "Color": "Red",
            "Cylinders": "8",
            "Transmission": "Manual"
        }]
}';
    $cars = json_decode($carJson, true)['Inventory'];


    $posts = [
        'Model' => ['Mustang', 'Camero'],
        'Color' => ['Red']
    ];

    $result = [];

    foreach ($posts as $postKey => $postValue) {
        foreach ($cars as $k => $car) {
            if (array_key_exists($postKey, $car) && in_array($car[$postKey], $postValue)) {
                $result[$k] = $car;
            } else {
                unset($cars[$k]);
                unset($result[$k]);
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($result);
```

Comment: I am sorry, but after testing, I noticed this only filters on the last array item.  It only filters on Color=Red, and is ignoring Mustang and Camaro.  'Model' => ['Mustang', 'Camaro'], 'Color' => ['Red'].  Adding another vehicle that is red, such as a red VW will also be included in the results.

Comment: please check $result